# Ef don't see migration changes when change navigation property from derived to base

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

So,I will present my case.Before I had such structure

```
public abstract class Base
{
   public int BaseId { get; set;}
}

public class Derived : Base
{
   public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntities{get;set;}
}

public class SomeEntity
{
   public int SomeEntityId { get; set;}
   public int DerivedId {get;set;}
   public virtual Derived Derived{ get; set;}
}
```

And Mapping:

```
public class BaseMap
{
   ToTable("Base");
}
public class DerivedMap
{
   ToTable("Derived");
}
public class SomeEntityMap
{
    HasRequired(t => t.Derived)
            .WithMany(t => t.SomeEntities)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DerivedId);
}
```

It works ok.But I had to link SomeEntity not to derived class ,but to base.So I changed structue properly:

```
public abstract class Base
{
   public int BaseId { get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntities{get;set;} //moved to base
}

public class Derived : Base
{

}

public class SomeEntity
{
   public int SomeEntityId { get; set;}
   public int DerivedId { get; set;}
   public virtual Base Derived{ get; set;} // changed type to base
}
```

And Mapping remain the same:

```
public class BaseMap
{
   ToTable("Base");
}
public class DerivedMap
{
   ToTable("Derived");
}
public class SomeEntityMap
{
    HasRequired(t => t.Derived)
            .WithMany(t => t.SomeEntities)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DerivedId);
}
```

The problem is after these changes and call add-migration entity framework haven't seen any changes and generated empty migration.

Is it ef bag or I did something wrong?

Comment: so what did you expect it to be changed? Looks like the database structure does not change, does that? I mean the migration has something only when there is something changed to the database other than to the entity model.

Comment: No,At first in database table SomeEntities has relatioship with table Derives,after my changes It should has relationship with table Bases

Comment: I see there are just 2 tables `BaseEntity` and `Derived`, after the change, there are still just 2 those tables. So where is the `Bases`?

Comment: There are 3 tables(Base,Derived and SomeEntity)

Comment: Are you sure the first case creates a relationship with table Derived? It seems to me that both cases will generate a FK to Base table. You changed the location of the collection, but that is just an EF trick. You could even remove the collection and the whole thing would still work the same way.